# I need to join one table and one sub-query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
(
   SELECT eid  FROM Assignment
   GROUP BY eid
   HAVING SUM(hours_per_week) > 40
)
```

This is my code for finding hours_per_week that is over 40. The sub-query returns the eid's of the people with more than 40 hours. My question is how would I display all of the people in Employee with the eid i got from the sub-query. A where? or a join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)`

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM Employee
WHERE eid IN
(
   SELECT eid  FROM Assignment
   GROUP BY eid
   HAVING SUM(hours_per_week) > 40
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Employee AS e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT eid
   FROM Assignment
   GROUP BY eid
   HAVING SUM(hours_per_week) > 40
) AS ot ON ot.eid = e.eid
```

Comment: That's how I'd have done it as well, give the query optimser more elbow room

Answer (score 0):

```
Select E.EID, sum(A.hours_per_Week)
FROM employee E 
INNER join Assignment A on E.EID = A.EID
Group By E.EID 
Having sum(A.Hours_per_week) > 40
```

Why do you need the subquery?